# Get next business day using ant

Tags: java, time, ant, days

In the project I'm working on there is a number of scripts that use ant to generate reports. Today date is initiated this way:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="today.date" pattern="yyyyMMdd"/>
</tstamp>
```

How can I get next business day from it using ant? Business day means adding +1 if today is Sunday..Thursday, +3 if Friday, +2 if Saturday.

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this is to write the logic in a Java class and invoke it from Ant. Doing this in pure Ant might be possible, but would be quite long and ugly.

Comment: Decided to count number of days to add in switch-case and then call tstamp with offset parameter